# Alpha Axp シミュレーターのBlissがビルド出来ない

Tags: c++

こんにちは。
早速ですが、Windows10 Home上のcygwin64でBliss( https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~oskin/Bliss/ )のビルドができません。
たくさん修正したのですが、Standart.hにPort.hとMessageChannel.hを加えたり、SendMessage関数の引数の順番を定義のものにそろえたり、SimpleClockedMemoryBus.cxxに関数を加えたり、MakefileのAlphaProcessor.iをAlphaProcessor.oにコンパイルするルールを書き加えたりなどしたのですが、最後のリンクで書き込んであるマクロがないと言われたりして、ビルドを成功させることができません。どなたかうまくいった方、いらっしゃいましたら、教えてください。
お願いします。具体的なソースは長すぎるので載せられません。すみません。